# angle attribute in android gradient

Tags: android, android-layout, gradient, android-shape

I am going through test example. Where for some Image background they are using gradient,
the code goes like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>


  <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#ff0000"
        android:centerColor="#00ff00"
        android:endColor="#0000ff"
        android:angle="180"/>
    <corners android:radius="5dp" />
   </shape>
```

In the above xml I didn't get `angle` attribute. but when I change the value of `angle` slightly the pattern slants. Can anyone explain me how exactly it works?

Answer (score 185):

Gradient basically represents the variation in space(in a direction) of any quantity. With color it represents the variation of color intensity in a direction represented by angle. Here are some diagrams to represent this concept:
[image]

Here the figure shows the color variation in horizontal direction (angle is set 0).
XML code:

```
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#000000"
        android:angle="0"/>
   </shape>
```

[image]

Here the figure shows the color variation in vertical direction (angle is set 90).
XML code:

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<gradient
    android:startColor="#000000"
    android:angle="90"/>
 </shape>
```

You can also use different color as start, center and end colors. The code you attached contains all these elements.

Comment: Thanks for answer Karn, but one thing I found that I can give only multiples of 45 in angle attribute, other than that it crashes i.e 20, 20 ,50 etc

Comment: There are many ways in which gradient can be expressed. Here we are actually using Linear gradient(slope along a straight line slope     m=(y-y1)/(x-x1)). When it is multiple of 45 the variation in x and y is same. May be cause of this reason. I don't know much.

Comment: Being the starter color is black (#000000) seems as the arrows are going in the oposite direction, no?

Comment: @Im2a The start is from the left hand side and it then rotates in anticlockwise direction. Just try changing the angle in your xml and you will see it happening.

Comment: @karn  am really confused with your answer here. the start is from left to right in anticlockwise direction. so in image 1, i expect the arrows to move like this ->->->-> . also am confused with the with way `android:startColor="#000000"` works. if we put start angle of 90, does it mean from angle 90-270 the color will be black ? what about the remaining angle(0-90)?

Comment: @gikarasojo kinene The answer is correct. Except ,from trigonometry point of view the vector desribing an angle starts from origin (beginning of coordinates). Angle is being mesured in counterclockwise  direction. So when the angle is 90(pi/2) the ort vector looks upword. Hence , the arrows in above answer are directed wrong. Contrary.The same is with first picture.

Comment: What is the default angle?

Comment: @sandeepmaaram default is 0

Answer (score 19):

More simply, give the angle value relative to the point where you want it to start.

[image]

It will start with startColor according to the **angle** value.

Example for 90:

[image]

Example for 270:

[image]

Comment: This is the best answer. It really helped me understand how gradient angles work.

Comment: it helped and easy to understand angels thanks.

Answer (score 18):

Specifies a gradient color for the shape.
attributes:

android:angle
Integer. The angle for the gradient, in degrees. 0 is left to right, 90 is bottom to top. It must be a multiple of 45. Default is 0.

It seems that the description in the documentation contradict to karn's answer??

You can find more details in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape)

Comment: You had me at `must be a multiple of 45`

Comment: Yea, is there anyway to get around this 45 degree angle rule without using a SWEEP_GRADIENT?

Comment: @Mr.Drew You can create different angles with the first 4 parameters of LinearGradient as described in [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25935582/6012281).

Use `linearGradient.setLocalMartix()` to scale it to the desired size afterwards.

Comment: Angle attribute is 0 by default for Android <=9. For Android 10 it's 270 [official doc](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-all#gradient-angle)

Answer (score 12):

you might wanna create diagonal gradient from code. It's much easier and you have a lot of options open from there. This snippet helped me

```
public void SetGradient(View view) {
        GradientDrawable gd = new GradientDrawable(
                GradientDrawable.Orientation.TL_BR,
                new int[]{0xFF141a24, 0xFF293f49, 0xFF72554c});
        view.setBackground(gd);
    }
```

available directions from GradientDrawable class

```
/*public enum Orientation {
        *//** draw the gradient from the top to the bottom *//*
        TOP_BOTTOM,
        *//** draw the gradient from the top-right to the bottom-left *//*
        TR_BL,
        *//** draw the gradient from the right to the left *//*
        RIGHT_LEFT,
        *//** draw the gradient from the bottom-right to the top-left *//*
        BR_TL,
        *//** draw the gradient from the bottom to the top *//*
        BOTTOM_TOP,
        *//** draw the gradient from the bottom-left to the top-right *//*
        BL_TR,
        *//** draw the gradient from the left to the right *//*
        LEFT_RIGHT,
        *//** draw the gradient from the top-left to the bottom-right *//*
        TL_BR,
    }*/
```

and you call the method from onCreate or onCreateView in fragment and pass parent view(in my case).

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.dialog_view_parent, container);           
        ...

        SetGradient(view);

        return view;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I've made a universal solution that supports any angle on jetpack, and wrote a [medium article](https://medium.com/@bimurat.mukhtar/how-to-implement-linear-gradient-with-any-angle-in-jetpack-compose-3ded798c81f5) about it (thanks to the first solution for the idea). Check it out if necessary