# How to set gradient on TextView color with angle?

Tags: android, textview, gradient, angle, textcolor

Following code will set gradient on textview (not background, but text itself). But I need to change angle of this gradient, how to do it?

```
Shader textShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, 0, textView.getPaint().getTextSize(),
        new int[]{context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color1), context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color2)},
        new float[]{0, 1}, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
textView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2):

According to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25935582/1162154), I modified your code. Try this:

```java
double angleInRadians = Math.toRadians(45);
double length = textView.getPaint().getTextSize();

double endX = Math.sin(angleInRadians) * length;
double endY = Math.cos(angleInRadians) * length;

Shader textShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, endX, endY,
        new int[]{context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color1), context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color2)},
        new float[]{0, 1}, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
textView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
```

**Update:**
I'm ashamed to say that my above answer is not correct. These answers ([mayank1513 answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60053227/1162154) and [Chaudhari Sachin answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60053992/1162154)) are the same and they are good but they have few bugs:

1. They don't work correctly for agnles more than 90 degrees. For exmaple if you test them with 180 degrees, then you won't see any gradient, because these solutions are using (0,0) point as rotation center.

2. If you have a TextView with width or height more or less than its text width or height, then gradient doesn't render correctly. For example you can test it by a TextView with `match_parent` width and height and centered `Hello` text or with an enabled scrolling small TextView and long text.

I developed new soltuion. It calcuates text bound first and then rotates gradient line around center of this bound.

```java
textView.post(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {

        final Rect textBound = new Rect(Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MAX_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE, Integer.MIN_VALUE);

        final Layout layout = textView.getLayout();
        for(int i = 0; i < textView.getLineCount(); i++) {
            float left = layout.getLineLeft(i);
            float right = layout.getLineRight(i);
            if(left < textBound.left) textBound.left = (int)left;
            if(right > textBound.right) textBound.right = (int)right;
        }
        textBound.top = layout.getLineTop(0);
        textBound.bottom = layout.getLineBottom(textView.getLineCount() - 1);
        if(textView.getIncludeFontPadding()) {
            Paint.FontMetrics fontMetrics = textView.getPaint().getFontMetrics();
            textBound.top += (fontMetrics.ascent - fontMetrics.top);
            textBound.bottom -= (fontMetrics.bottom - fontMetrics.descent);
        }

        double angleInRadians = Math.toRadians(45);

        double r = Math.sqrt(Math.pow(textBound.bottom - textBound.top, 2) +
                Math.pow(textBound.right - textBound.left, 2)) / 2;

        float centerX = textBound.left + (textBound.right - textBound.left) / 2;
        float centerY = textBound.top + (textBound.bottom - textBound.top) / 2;

        float startX = (float)Math.max(textBound.left, Math.min(textBound.right, centerX - r * Math.cos(angleInRadians)));
        float startY = (float)Math.min(textBound.bottom, Math.max(textBound.top, centerY - r * Math.sin(angleInRadians)));

        float endX = (float)Math.max(textBound.left, Math.min(textBound.right, centerX + r * Math.cos(angleInRadians)));
        float endY = (float)Math.min(textBound.bottom, Math.max(textBound.top, centerY + r * Math.sin(angleInRadians)));

        Shader textShader = new LinearGradient(startX, startY, endX, endY,
                new int[]{context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color1),
                        context.getResources().getColor(R.color.color2)},
                new float[]{0, 1}, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        textView.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        textView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
    }
});
```

Comment: Gradient appear only on first character -- other characters are single colored

Comment: This answer is based on your code and and I used `new float[] {0, 1}` as `Positions` parameter. You can use null to make it linear. Based on official documentation: "float: May be null. The relative positions [0..1] of each corresponding color in the colors array. If this is null, the the colors are distributed evenly along the gradient line. This value may be null."

Comment: float[] is not an issue. Issue is with measuring textwidth

Comment: It gives text height not width --- gradient spans only first character.

Answer (score 2):

```
final TextView myTextView = findViewById(R.id.my_text_view);

myTextView.post(new Runnable() 
    {

         @Override

            public void run() {

                int length = textView.getMeasuredWidth();

            float angle = 45; // specify angle in degrees here

            Shader textShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, (int) (Math.sin(Math.PI * angle / 180) * length), 
                                    (int) (Math.cos(Math.PI * angle / 180) * length),

                                        new int[]{Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.RED},

    null, 
        Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);

        myTextView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);

            textView.invalidate();

            }

    });
```

[image: result]

Comment: From Review:  Hi, please don't answer just with source code. Try to provide a nice description about how your solution works. See: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Working code

```
final double angleInRadians = Math.toRadians(45);
final TextView textView = findViewById(R.id.app_name);
    textView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            double length = textView.getMeasuredWidth();

            double endX = Math.sin(angleInRadians) * length;
            double endY = Math.cos(angleInRadians) * length;

            Shader textShader = new LinearGradient(0, 0, (int) endX, (int) endY,
                    new int[]{Color.BLUE, Color.GREEN, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.GREEN, Color.BLUE, Color.RED},
                    null, Shader.TileMode.CLAMP);
            textView.getPaint().setShader(textShader);
            textView.invalidate();
        }
    });
```

This sets gradient with specified angle.

Comment: Why are you using `Runnable` and post it? You can make changes without Runnable. In addition you don't need to invalidate textview.

Comment: If don't use post, measured width is zero -- using it in onCreate

Comment: if use posr then invalidate is necessary else changes won't show up

Comment: endX + endYY always = 0