# Rotating the gradient not the oval

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, gradient

I have an oval shape with a sweep gradient, I want to rotate the gradient not the oval itself (since when I rotate oval it is not in the right position anymore). I couldn't find anything about this. Any ideas? This is what I'm trying to do

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<layer-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <item>

        <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:shape="oval">
            <stroke
                android:width="1dp"
                android:color="#585858" />
            <rotate
                android:fromDegrees="0"
                android:pivotX="50%"
                android:pivotY="50%"
                android:toDegrees="40">
                <gradient
                    android:endColor="#FF7DD6"
                    android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
                    android:type="sweep"
                    android:useLevel="false" />
            </rotate>

        </shape>

    </item>

</layer-list>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using SweepGradient there is setLocalMatrix method that could be used:

```
 float initial_rotation_angle_degrees = 30; 
 SweepGradient gradient = new SweepGradient(0,0
                        ,new int[]{
                        ,0xff0078be
                        ,0xfff4535c
                        }
                        ,null);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
// Rotating the gradient 
        matrix.postRotate(initial_rotation_angle_degrees);
// Translating the gradient (The initial cx, cy values must be 0)
        matrix.postTranslate(cx,cy);
        gradient.setLocalMatrix(matrix);
```

Comment: The method `postRotate(float degrees, float px, float py)` also helpful. it will rotate base on `px `and `py`

Answer (score 1):

`gradient` has an attribute `angle` that takes an int value  to give direction to a gradient.

According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Shape):

> The angle for the gradient, in degrees. 0 is left to right, 90 is bottom to top. **It must be a multiple of 45**. Default is 0.

By changing the angle, this should rotate your gradient.

An example might be:

```
<gradient
     android:endColor="#FF7DD6"
     android:startColor="#FFFFFF"
     android:type="sweep"
     android:angle="270"
     android:useLevel="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Unfortunately, That doesn't work for sweep gradient but it works for linear gradient [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153890/angle-attribute-in-android-gradient)

Comment: Apologies @cagdas, I didn't initially notice it was a sweep.