# how to give 20 degree angle in gradient?

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I want to give 20 degree angle in the gradient what i have to do to achieve that?This is my xml code.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:shape="rectangle">
        <gradient android:startColor="#eeeeee"
            android:endColor="#ffffff"
            android:angle="0" />
    </shape>
```

Comment: may be 20 gradient is not supporting in gradient. i also tried it but didn't get success for same. you can refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/12155542/3713967 for more details

Comment: @Dinesh 20 degree is not supported

Answer (score 3):

It seems like only multiples of 45 are accepted as an angle.

From doc: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource#Shape

> **android:angle**
>   Integer. The angle for the gradient, in degrees. 0 is left to right, 90 is bottom to top. It must be a multiple of 45. Default is 0.

To achieve the same effect, you could perhaps try to overlay a horizontal gradient with a partially transparent vertical gradient.

Answer (score 1):

according to the documentation

> Angle of the gradient, used only with linear gradient. Must be a multiple of 45 in the range [0, 315].

Comment: Is there any other way to achieve this?

Comment: you can always give a angle to your view !

Answer (score 0):

```
android:angle
```

According to [Official Documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/GradientDrawable.html#attr_android:angle) you can only use the multiples of 45 as gradient angle (in degrees). 0 is left to right, 90 is bottom to top. The default value is 0.

Comment: Is there any other way ?

Comment: @DineshS Using XML, I think No.