# How to make white buttons visible on a white image

Tags: android, user-interface, android-imageview

I have some texts and buttons that are displaying on an image view, where the image view can contain images of any color but the problem occurs with a white image if the text and button on the image view is in white and the image is also white the text and buttons will not be visible but I want to use the text and button color as white, is there any solutions for this I have added elevation but its not working

examples

1 this is an image that is colorful so the buttons are visible almost properly [SS](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ODtpsSawebJXYjrDYduxaFmliZGhj2D3/view?usp=sharing)

2 this is an image that has the most white color so the buttons are not visible at all [SS](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1O90_0X82wSTLHajkiwNlZuL_ojKSOS2k/view?usp=sharing)

I know I'm asking a dumb kind of question how can a white color button or text be visible on a white image, sorry for that but i cant change the layout now

> If you want more references of the code please tell me I will update
> the question

**imagepost_buttons.xml** // this is the layout that contains the texts and the buttons, not the main image view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutImagePost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/userName_Search_10List"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="15dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@string/iansomerhalder"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="15sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap" />


    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_post_option_icon_24" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/fav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="10dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="19dp"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_save_border_24" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/comment"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/fav"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_icons8_comment_icon" />


    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/unPressedLike"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/comment"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_heart_border_24"
        android:visibility="visible" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/likePressed"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="20dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/comment"
        android:contentDescription="@string/todo"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_baseline_heart_red_24"
        android:visibility="invisible" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/comentcount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@id/fav"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@string/_125"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal"
        tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap,SmallSp" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginEnd="9dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="6dp"
        android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/comment"
        android:elevation="50dp"
        android:fontFamily="@font/roboto"
        android:text="@string/_1_2k"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="10sp"
        android:textStyle="bold|normal"
        tools:ignore="RelativeOverlap,SmallSp" />


</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set some dark gradient at the bottom of the image to make sure the white text will be visible. Create a gradient drawable:

**gradient.xml**

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <gradient
        android:startColor="#FF000000"
        android:endColor="#00000000"
        android:angle="90" />    
</shape>
```

Then add it to Your layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayoutImagePost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient">

    ...

</RelativeLayout>
```

You can try adding this type of gradient to the image itself, but it would propably require You to scale the gradient a little bit.

Comment: thanks for the answer it's working, but it makes the image darker, which I'm sorry but I don't want that, is there any other  way

Comment: Are You applying the gradient to the image itself or the layout with the text and buttons? Because You don't want the gradient to fill the whole image - only the area with buttons and text.

Comment: in the layout not in the imageview

Comment: Can You show how it looks?

Comment: ok I have a idea  what if we just gradient the bottom, can you suggest to me a startColor that is almost transparent so the image doesn't lose it original color

Comment: I would use something lighter than black like `#88000000`

Comment: colorful image https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OGdzhUNPHwWw7JCm87j3bSsvv-fM2D7R/view?usp=sharing

Comment: white image https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OMF47dtUAER-Y8DKlhqNsBgjY1RVkiCx/view?usp=sharing

Comment: I think this is way better now, but try increasing the transparency of the black until it is as light as possible and the text can still be visible.

Comment: ok i have used #88000000 this and it worked, https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ORzH6aInMTZCiWLblvvhspurM5hhhkDQ/view?usp=sharing  , is there any way to just add endColor and not startColor

Comment: Gradient has to have two colors it makes transition through, so both start and end colours are required.

Comment: hey can you tell me what is android:angle="90" i mean what it does

Comment: It specifies the angle of direction of the gradient. You can try to delete this attribute and see what happens, this will help You understand.

Comment: ok, i understand it set the direction of the gradient as angle,90 means the 90-degree angle, am I right?

Comment: if we don't specify the startColor starts from the left and goes to the right

Comment: Here is nice follow-up on the angle attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12153890/angle-attribute-in-android-gradient

Comment: thanks for your help

Comment: can you give me a suggestion, as you can see from the images I have shared, is it is a good UI design for the image view or I just separate all the buttons and the text views in a different segment and leave the image view alone (I'm trying to develop a social media app )

Comment: because if the image is bright enough there is not much a problem, but not every user has some kind of image brightness

Comment: I think that this is all up to You now :D

Comment: yup , btw thanks once again for your efforts for solving my question